# Bootstrap 3 + Firefox appearance bug when back from Windows task bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have a very odd and specific problem, not sure if it's a bug in Bootstrap or Firefox, and no real lead how to fix (or even patch) it.

We only saw it with Bootstrap web sites: our own, as well as [Bootstrap's own web site](http://getbootstrap.com/).
If you open the page on Firefox, in an external display, reduce Firefox to window's task bar, and bring it back, then the web site appears all zoomed up, with some content missing. Strangely enough, we seem to reproduce this only on laptops when opening the web page on the external display.

I posted the before / after images below.

Do anyone have a clue what's happening here ? Should we send the bug to Firefox ? Bootstrap ? Any idea how to prevent it ?

Thanks in advance

[image: Before]
[image]

Comment: Test it on many devices but can't reproduce this :(

Comment: Really ! Strange... We tested it on two different laptops (a windows and a windows on bootcamp), with the same issue. But only when Firefox is displayed on an external display connected to the laptop. If opened on the laptop's screen, then no problem... :/

Comment: Also if we mirror the display, the problem doesn't appear. Maybe the bug's roots are directly in Windows ? (we're both on Windows 10)

Comment: Here also working with normal Windows 10 and a Bootcamp version included FireFox installed, can't reproduce this.

Comment: Hmm strange. Could there be something else ? Thanks for the info !